# MSBuild returns non-zero errorlevel in CMD and Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt, but not PowerShell

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I'm having an issue where when I try to run builds using MSBuild, I get a non-zero `errorlevel` (-1073741819).  While researching this issue, I noticed I got this error level if I ran `msbuild` in the Command Prompt or VS2017 Developer Command Prompt, but not in PowerShell.

In PowerShell, if I run `msbuild /?` I get the normal usage information.  However, in Command Prompt or VS2017 Develper Command Prompt, `msbuild /?` produced the same error code as above with no output.  For example, in the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt I see:

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.7.5
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************

C:\Windows\System32>msbuild /?

C:\Windows\System32>echo %errorlevel%
-1073741819
```

However, in PowerShell I see this:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> msbuild /?
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.7.180.61344 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

<<... Detailed flag options displayed here ...>>
```

According to PowerShell `Get-Command`, it's using `msbuild.exe` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`.  Setting the `/verbosity:` flag doesn't seem to change the output.

In the event log, I'm seeing the error with the error: `Exception code: 0xc0000005`.

### My Path:

```
C:\tools\ruby23\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\windows\system32
C:\windows
C:\windows\System32\Wbem
C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
C:\Program Files\dotnet\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\Program Files\OpenSSH-Win64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\Best Practices Analyzer\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools\Best Practices Analyzer\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\atom\bin
C:\Program Files\Collaborator Client
```

Answer (score 0):

> MSBuild returns non-zero errorlevel in CMD and Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt, but not PowerShell

It seems your Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt has not been initialized successfully. You can try to execute `VsDevCmd.bat` in the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt:

Location: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\Tools`

If this `.bat` can not be executed successfully, you can try to repair or reinstall the Visual Studio.

**Update:**

> I'm seeing an exception code for msbuild in the Event log: Exception
>   code: 0xc0000005. Google hasn't produced much unfortunately

It seems the exception code 0xc0000005 is related to access violation. When you execute your command can you switch to use admin privilege? You may need to check the permission of your account. And you also need to check if Virus scanner is disabled.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried a reinstall of Visual Studio, Developer Build Tools, and MSBuild and have had no luck.  One thing I did notice was that the version of MSBuild located in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64` works.  I added the `-arch=amd64` arugment to dev tools and it seems to try to use that version.  `where msbuild` shows two versions; one in the directory above, and one in the VS2017\Professional\MSBuild directory, which still fails.  If I could get it to use the one in `Framework64` by default, I'd be in good shape.

Comment: I would have thought a reinstall of Visual Studio would have fixed it.  I'm not sure what triggered this problem to begin with.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I've reinstalled VS2017 multiple times.  Every time msbuild fails silently, even if I just try to get usage information (`msbuild /?`).  I've tried launching it with multiple architectures (`amd64`/`x86`) and have had no luck.

One thing I have noticed is that the version of `msbuild` located in  `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\` seems to work.  However, it doesn't seem to use that version.

Comment: Tried a repair as well with no luck.

Comment: I'm seeing an exception code for `msbuild` in the Event log: `Exception code: 0xc0000005`.  Google hasn't produced much unfortunately =/

Comment: @bsjohnson61, Thanks for your reply. It seems the exception code 0xc0000005 is related to access violation. When you execute your command can you switch to use admin privilege? You may need to check the permission of your account. And you also need to check if Virus scanner is disabled.